# Running Windows 7 Virtualbox on Ubuntu command Line

Tags: windows, ubuntu, command-line, virtualbox

Is it possible to run a windows virtualbox and possibly control it using nothing but a command line from ubuntu?

I will also need to access regedit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Run your VM from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445284/how-to-start-a-virtualbox-machine-via-command-line-without-gui/449249): `VBoxManage startvm nameOfYourVBox --type headless`
2. Console access to your VM: [You'll need an SSH server for Windows](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server)
   then `ssh myUserName@myBoxIp`
3. Acces to Regedit: it's a graphical program, so you can't use it just from command line. An CLI alternate is the `reg` command, more info with `reg /?`.